# Summarise medication dates based on instance of prescribing

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a long dataset (25k rows) where each row represents a **dose** of a certain `med`ication given to a person (`id`) on a given day (`adm_date`).

I'm now trying to summarise this dataset so that each row represents a **course** of a `med` for a given `id`, with columns indicating start date and end date. Each course can last any number of days.

```r
    library(dplyr)
    df <- tribble(~id, ~med,  ~adm_date,   ~start, ~end,
            1,  "antibiotic", "13/01/2022", TRUE, NA,
            1,  "antibiotic", "14/01/2022", NA,   TRUE,
            1,  "antibiotic", "21/01/2022", TRUE, NA,
            1,  "antibiotic", "22/02/2022", NA,   NA,
            1,  "antibiotic", "23/02/2022", NA,   TRUE,
            1,  "aspirin",    "14/01/2022", TRUE, TRUE,
            2,  "antibiotic", "14/01/2022", TRUE, NA,
            2,  "antibiotic", "15/01/2022", NA,   TRUE,
            2,  "aspirin",    "14/01/2022", TRUE, TRUE)
```

Intended output:

| id | med | course | course_start | course_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | antibiotic | 1 | 13/01/2022 | 14/01/2022 |
| 1 | antibiotic | 2 | 21/01/2022 | 23/02/2022 |
| 1 | aspirin | 1 | 14/01/2022 | 14/01/2022 |
| 2 | antibiotic | 1 | 14/01/2022 | 15/01/2022 |
| 2 | aspirin | 1 | 14/01/2022 | 14/01/2022 |

I can't simply use `group_by(id, med) %>% summarise(course_start = min(adm_date), course_end = max(adm_date)` because a medication can be prescribed in more than one course (e.g. two instances for the same antibiotic: 13-14 Jan, 21-22 Jan; the code above would merge the two into 13-22 Jan).

My approach is:

1. I coded columns `start` and `end` to identify the start and end of each course (Done - see sample dataset).
2. Using these to create a `course` (instance) column. (**Don't know how to do this**).
3. `df |> group_by(id, med, course) |> summarise(course_start = min(adm_date), course_end = max(adm_date)` (This should work).

(Of course, happy with any other approach).

(PS: this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71581786/getting-the-start-and-end-dates-of-a-patient-with-the-possibility-of-multiple), however I don't have another factor that separates instances, so I can't use Stefano's brilliant solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>% 
  filter(!(is.na(start) & is.na(end))) %>% 
  group_by(med, id) %>% 
  mutate(course_start = if_else(start == T, adm_date, NA_character_),
         course_end = if_else(is.na(end), lead(adm_date), course_start)) %>% 
  drop_na(course_start) %>% 
  select(id, med, starts_with("course")) %>% 
  mutate(course = row_number(), .after = med) %>% 
  ungroup

# A tibble: 5 x 5
     id med        course course_start course_end
  <dbl> <chr>       <int> <chr>        <chr>     
1     1 antibiotic      1 13/01/2022   14/01/2022
2     1 antibiotic      2 21/01/2022   23/02/2022
3     1 aspirin         1 14/01/2022   14/01/2022
4     2 antibiotic      1 14/01/2022   15/01/2022
5     2 aspirin         1 14/01/2022   14/01/2022
```

Comment: This is really useful, thanks. However my dataset is more complicated - courses can last any number of days, so `course_end = if_else(is.na(end), lead(adm_date), course_start))` does not capture the end date for all courses that last more than 2 days. I've now edited the sample dataset to show this - apologies.

Comment: I think you can just start with a filter on is.na(start) & is.na(end) in that case, I've updated it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. First `group_by(id, med)` so that they're treated as a group
2. Create a `course_end` column by `ifelse`. If `end` is `NA`, set the next row of `adm_date` as the `course_end`. If it's not `NA`, use the `adm_date`.
3. Rename `adm_date` to `start_date`
4. Remove rows that contain `NA` in the `start` column
5. Remove `start` and `end` columns
6. Create a `course` column by forcing `med` into numeric column and calculate the `cumsum` of it.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(id, med) %>% 
  mutate(course_end = ifelse(is.na(end), lead(adm_date), adm_date)) %>% 
  rename("start_date" = "adm_date") %>% 
  drop_na(start) %>% 
  select(-start, -end) %>% 
  mutate(course = cumsum(as.numeric(as.factor(med))))

# A tibble: 5 × 5
# Groups:   id, med [4]
     id med        start_date course_end course
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>
1     1 antibiotic 13/01/2022 14/01/2022      1
2     1 antibiotic 21/01/2022 22/02/2022      2
3     1 aspirin    14/01/2022 14/01/2022      1
4     2 antibiotic 14/01/2022 15/01/2022      1
5     2 aspirin    14/01/2022 14/01/2022      1
```